# HTML label elements on PHP includes on IE

Tags: php, internet-explorer, input, include, label

I have a question about a Weird thing that happens to me on one of my projects.
When creating a simple php file with an html like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sample" />
<label for="sample">Click</label>
```

then clicking on the label will select the checkbox, but when I create the same code in an external file and use the php include function, the label doesn't work for the checkbox on IE!

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
<?php include "myInclude.php"; ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

When myInclude.php is:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sample" />
<label for="sample">Click</label>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Impossible. You are missing something (doing or telling us).

Comment: Show us the generated output from the PHP include.

Answer (score 0):

Something might be wrong with the output markup, verify in the view source it matches your non-including sample.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Matt Lo's answer: Maybe there's another element with the ID 'sample'? Also check your Markup with the W3C validator.